# Real-time image thumbnail creator website

Tags: web-services, image-processing, thumbnails

Is there a real-time image thumbnail creator website around? By that I mean a web service (with a simple API) which can provide a thumbnail of an image provided by the URL. I don't mind a watermark (although I prefer it not be there) and I don't have that many images to convert. Thanks.